# Post filter Month dropdown at front-end like wordpress backend

Tags: filters, archives

when i run the following code.

```
$args = array(
    'type'            => 'monthly',
    'limit'           => '',
    'format'          => 'option', 
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => 1,
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'     => 'post'
)
```

```
<select>
<option value=""> Select </option>
<?php 
    wp_get_archives( $args ); 
?>  </select>
```

I got this output

```
<select>
<option> Select </option>
    <option value="http://test.astech-us.com/holistichivorce/2016/03/"> March 2016 </option>
<option value="http://test.astech-us.com/holistichivorce/2016/02/"> February 2016 </option></select>
```

but i need output like WordPress back end filter option. like this

```
    <select name="m" id="filter-by-date"><option selected="selected" value="0">All dates</option><option value="201603">March 2016</option><option value="201602">February 2016</option></select>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_get_archives`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/#source-code) creates its links with the function [`get_archives_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_archives_link/#source-code). this function returns plain HTML, but it has a filter you can hook into.

You can use the [`get_archives_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_archives_link/) filter to manipulate your HTML with some regex.

```
function my_archives_link($link_html) {
    //TODO: my regex to manipulate the HTML
    return $link_html;
}

add_filter('get_archives_link','my_archives_link')
```

### Further reading

- [wp_get_archives](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/#source-code)
- [get_archives_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_archives_link/#source-code)
- Filter Hook: [get_archives_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_archives_link/)